# Join two tables based on a view, sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql situation

```
Table1
 id name

Table2
 id name

_Table1ToTable2
 id, id_table1, id_table2

Result:
 id, name, table2_name, table2_id
```

I would like to join Table1 and Table2 into a single query, but I cannot find a way to make a join between them, any ideas?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: @sgeddes done!!

Comment: Sample data means actual data we can work with. Also, how do the tables relate to each other ? What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: @Tony relationship is on the _Table1ToTable2 table view, basically, it's a 1 to 1 relation between the 2, this is a mysql table

Comment: can Table1 and Table2 have different number or rows? in the result, would you like to see nulls if either Table1 or 2 corresponding row is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to use bridge table `Table1ToTable2` to join `Table1` and `Table2`. This can be done simply with 2 `INNER JOIN`s :

```
SELECT
    tt.id AS tt_id,
    t1.id AS t1_id,
    t1.name AS t1_name,
    t2.id AS t2_id,
    t2.name AS t2_name
FROM
    Table1ToTable2 AS tt
    INNER JOIN Table1 AS t1
        ON t1.id = tt.id_table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
        ON t2.id = tt.id_table2
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no relationship between table1 and table 2 then,

```
select table1.id, table1.name, table2.id, table2.name from
table1, table2
```

if table1 and table2 are related with ID then,

```
select  table1.id, table1.name, table2.id, table2.name from
table1
inner join table2
  on table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to retrieve a result set with every possible combination of the id columns from both tables then you can do as follows:

`select id = identity (int, 1, 1), * into #a from (select distinct table1. id as id1, table2. id as id2 from table1 cross apply table2) d; select * from #a; drop table #a`

If you do not wish to use a temp table an alternative would be to use some variation of the row_number() function.

The above solves for an assumed requirement as your question lacks context. Elaborate on your requirements and we will be able to provide you with a more relevant and detailed answer.